# Matching digits and text in a string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does *percent* not get matched in the the following regular expression

```
/(^(?:[\d\.]+|first|second|goal))(?:\w+(interval|percent))?/i
```

Input string example:

```
10percentRule
```

Comment: What does `\w+` match?

Comment: The common practice on SO is to accept the correct answer provided first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not get matched because `\w+` requires at least 1 word char between `10` and `percent`. Replace `+` (*one or more occurrences*) with `*` (*zero or more occurrences*):

```
(^(?:[\d\.]+|first|second|goal))(?:\w*(interval|percent))?
                                     ^
```

and it will work.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mu3W7V/2)

Answer (score 3):

/(^(?:[\d.]+|first|second|goal))(?:**\w+**(interval|percent))?/i

w+ is the problem here: you should use w*, w+ means 1 or more matches, while w* means 0 or more matches; in your example, 1st group captures the number digits, then searchs for at least 1 character (w+) brefore interval or percent,so, it doesn´t return any match.

Use w* instead, or even beter w*? (not-greedy), so it will stop searching characters when it find interval or percent

```
/(^(?:[\d.]+|first|second|goal))(?:\w*?(interval|percent))?/i
```

Comment: wanted to highlight w+, what was not possible in code mode, but I added a code line at the end. Hopefully will be enough